# Why is {a^n a^n | n >= 0} regular?

Tags: regular-language, fsm

I understand the reason and the proof why `{a^n b^n | n >= 0}` is NOT regular.
[Why is {a^nb^n | n >= 0} not regular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309752/why-is-anbn-n-0-not-regular)

The solution of one of my exercises is: `{a^n a^n | n >= 0}` is regular. How can I prove this thesis?

Comment: the accepted answer at [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2309755/1673391) using pumping is **wrong**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Language {a<sup>n</sup> a<sup>n</sup> | n >= 0} **is a regular language**. To proof that certain language is regular, you can draw its dfa/regular expression. And you can drive do for this language as follows:

Because "`anan` for `n >= 0`" is same as  "`a2n` for n >=0", and that  is "set of all string contests of even number of symbol `a`" **that is regular** — regular expression for this is `(aa)*`.

Note, regular expressions is only possible for regular languages hence it is proved that {a<sup>n</sup> a<sup>n</sup> | n >= 0} is a regular language. and DFA would be:

[image: dfa]

I would suggest you to read this [why languages like {a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>n</sup> | n >= 0} are not regular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16730707/1673391).

Answer (score 1):

First change the definition to the equivalent `L = {a^2n | n >= 0}`. Now observe that any string that belongs to `L` is simply a multiple of 2 `a`s. Then change that definition to `(aa)*`, which is a *regular expression* since it only uses primitives for expressing regular languages—individual characters (`a`), concatenation, (`aa`) and Kleene star (`*`). Now you're done.