# Pumping Lemma and Hierachy

Tags: theory, pumping-lemma, chomsky-hierarchy

I have a question involving the *Pumping Lemma for Regular Languages* and *Pumping Lemma for Context-free Languages*:
Is it possible that there's a language which doesn't meet the criteria for the *pumping-lemma for context-free languages* but does meet the criteria for the pumping-lemma for regular languges?

Or is there a hierachy similar to the Chomsky-Hierachy?

I'm just trying to understand that and pumping lemma in general

Comment: *Any* regular language won't satisfy the PL for CFLs but will for RLs; that's kind of the point.

Comment: I don't understand yet why because a regular language should be according to the chomsky-hierachy above the CFL and must then be a CFL itself and therefor should be able to meet the PL criteria for CFL or am I wrong?

Comment: And if a language does not satisfy the PL for CFL it should't be able to satisfy the PL for RL...or that's what I'm thinking right now

Comment: If the language is context free, but not regular you might be able to proof that using the PL for regular languages. But as that language is CF you can not use the PL for CFL to proof that is isn't.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that there's a language which doesn't meet the criteria for the pumping-lemma for context-free languages but does meet the criteria for the pumping-lemma for regular languges?

Let's consider the classic a^nb^n language. aabb is in it, while abb is not.

We know it is a CFL. (S -> aSb | *epsilon*)

We can proof that is is not a regular language using the PL for CFL (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309755)

The PL for CFL is used to proof that a language is NOT CF.
But the language IS CF (see above!).

Thus we can never use the PL for CFL for the language to proof that is it not CF.

---

> A regular language [...] must be a CFL itself and therefore should be able to meet the PL criteria for CFL or am I wrong?

Yes, any RL is also a CFL (and also a CSL and also a REL).
You are wrong in your conclusion though.

The PL is used to proof that a given language is NOT in the class. So we use the PL for RL to show that a language is not a RL, so "at most" CF. And we use the PL for CFL to show that a language is not even a CFL, so "at most" context sensitive.

---

> Is there a hierarchy similar to the Chomsky-Hierarchy ?

Well if you can proof a language is not context free, it can also not be regular, as RL is a subset of CFL.